# Getting java object back from JSON

Tags: java, json

I am putting some java objects in the Json at server side

like this :

```
      ArrayList<VisjsNode>visjsNodes = new ArrayList<VisjsNode>();
      ArrayList<VisjsConnection> visjsConnections = new ArrayList<VisjsConnection>();
      String jsondata = null;
      org.json.JSONObject object = new org.json.JSONObject();
    try {
        object.put("nodes", visjsNodes);
        object.put("connections", visjsConnections);
        jsondata = object.toString();
```

Now is there a way I can get these objects back from this json (jsondata) at client side

I am doing this:

```
            com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONValue jsonValue = JSONParser.parseStrict(jsondata);
            com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject jsonObject = jsonValue.isObject();
            jsonValue = jsonObject.get("nodes");
```

Now I am trying this to get ArrayList  back , by doing this

```
             ArrayList<VisjsNode>visjsNodesFromjson = jsonValue ;
```

But its not compiling ,it says Incompatable types...

Can you please guide how we can retrieve the Java Object back from Json ..

Comment: It's not something Java does by default, you need a library such as jackson on gson.

Comment: but these libraries are not working at client side ..and i need these objects at client side

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using two different JsonObject class. First you use the one which comes from org.json (org.json.JsonObject) and the other is com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject. Nevertheless, they're named similar, they're *completely* different classes.